# How to get hardware ID of network interface card in UEFI program?

Tags: uefi

[image: the hardware id of network interface card]

The form of hardware id of nic is like `PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_153A&SUBSYS_309717AA&REV_04`

I want to get it in UEFI program, but I haven't gotten any tips in UEFI specification.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, add code and description so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is **EFI_PCI_IO_PROTOCOL**.

Refer to UEFI spec 2.6 "***13.4 EFI PCI I/O Protocol***".

1. Get all PCI devices handles by calling gBS->LocateHandleBuffer().
2. Get EFI_PCI_IO_PROTOCOL attached on PCI device handle. (gBS->HandleProtocol)
3. Call EFI_PCI_IO_PROTOCOL.Pci() to load the PCI configuration space. Everything you need (Device id, Vendor id, Subsystem, Revision) can be found in PCI configuration space.